# Expect a method to be never called with certain arguments

Tags: php, phpunit

In PHPUnit how can I test if a method is never called with certain arguments? I mean that it can be called with any other arguments even multiple times but never with a certain one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's not possible using the standard way so you can use a callback for specifying the return value, and check the arguments there (bit tricky but seems to work):

```
$mock = $thi->getMockBuilder('MyClass')->getMock();
$mock->expects($this->any())
     ->method('myMethod')
     ->willReturnCallback(function() {
        $args = func_get_args();
        $disallowedArgs = [1, 'abc'];
        $this->assertNotEquals($disallowedArgs, $args);
    })
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass argument that should not be passed to the method and assert expect exception if your method is throwing one (which it probably should).

https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.exceptions.examples.ExceptionTest.php

Comment: You're assuming how the real method should work. The question is about mocking that method. Maybe the arguments are good for the real method but not valid in the test context.